# PrimeFaces component with outcome attribute renders incorrectly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**The problem**:

I have a MenuItem component that looks like this - `<p:menuitem value="Documents" outcome="/portal/admin/documents.xhtml" />` - but it renders into markup that looks like this - `<a href="documents.xhtml">`

---

**Details**:

There are two XHTML pages at play here.  The first is index.xhtml at `/portal/index.xhtml` and the second is admin-widget.xhtml at `/portal/home/admin-widget.xhtml`.

Relevant part of index.xhtml:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="...">
    <div class="...">
        <p:panel styleClass="...">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Administration" />
            </f:facet>
            <ui:include src="/portal/home/admin-widget.xhtml" />
        </p:panel>
    </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Relevant part of admin-widget.xhtml:

```
<h:form style="...">
    <ui:fragment rendered="...">
        <p:menu style="...">
            <p:submenu label="Administration Links">
                <p:menuitem value="Documents" outcome="/portal/admin/documents.xhtml" />
            </p:submenu>
        </p:menu>

        <h:link value="Documents" outcome="/portal/admin/documents.xhtml" />
    </ui:fragment>
</h:form>
```

The `<h:link>` below the `<p:menu>` was just a test, in order to see if the problem was just with the `<p:menuitem>` or not.  However, the `<h:link>` also renders incorrectly.

The most interesting thing is that when I view the index.xhtml page, the link is incorrect, but if I view the admin-widget.xhtml page directly, the link is correct.  So it has to be something with how I am inserting the page, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am using PrimeFaces 5.3 and JSF 2.0.